# обработчик событий не работает для добавленных через drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-n-drop

Проблема в том, что после того, как я добавляю элементы во время работы программы на страницу через `document.append`, к ним не применяется обработчики событий. Может кто работал с `dragndrop` уже сталкивался с этим.
Я понимаю, что инициализация их происходит при первой загрузке страницы, но можно ли как-то добавить обработчики к новым элементам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код обработки:

```js
$('#usingList').find('img').on('click', function (event) {
 debugger
 var dataUnicalid = event.target.getAttribute('unicalid');
 canvas.getObjects().forEach(function (o) {
  if (+o.unicalid === +dataUnicalid ) {
   canvas.setActiveObject(o).renderAll();
  }
 });
});
```

Обработчик событий, соответственно и `debugger` не срабатывает

Comment: покажите , как вы пробовали

Comment: @ddeadlink только скриншотами смогу. Ибо это канвас и это сложно формируемый объект с кучей атрибутов. Но берется сама картинка из html из списка

Comment: @ddeadlink добавил картинки, добавленные через dragndrop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно повесить событие на генируемые элементы с условием что `usingList` статичный.

```js
$('#usingList').on('click', 'img', function (event) {
 debugger
 var dataUnicalid = event.target.getAttribute('unicalid');
 canvas.getObjects().forEach(function (o) {
  if (+o.unicalid === +dataUnicalid ) {
   canvas.setActiveObject(o).renderAll();
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: вот только что оттестил похожий код. Сейчас по вашему отпишусь

Comment: все супер. Код срабатывает корректно и не на первый эллемент, это была моя ошибка